# I've upgraded from version 18.04 to 19.10, and now it performs very slowly?

Tags: 18.04, updates, 19.10

I updated the ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.10 . Now, it works very slow like 512mb ram. I allocated the swap space 3GiB and I have 4gb ram on my laptop and I run ubuntu single IS. Do you have any idea what might it be caused by ?

Comment: Did you re-install to get it to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.10?  (direct upgrades were tested & supported from 18.04 to 18.10 only, and will be tested & supported from 18.04 to 20.04 before 20.04.1 is released; other upgrade paths are not tested nor supported).  If you upgraded without a re-install, I'd probably evaluate how you did it as what you did was untested & thus unsupported by Ubuntu.  More details as to what you are running may help, and is your laptop thrashing (out-of-memory & thus swapping constantly, thus the reference to *like 512mb*?)

Comment: Show us the output of `top` and `free` while it is slow.